# calling javascript from gwt throws undefined is not a function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt

I need to adapt javascript from html template to my gwt code. 
The original code in head is:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slimbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slider").easySlider({
    auto: true,
    continuous: true,
    controlsShow:    false,
  });
});
</script>
```

and in body:

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="myapp/img/01.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="myapp/img/02.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="myapp/img/03.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="myapp/img/04.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="myapp/img/05.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have linked external javascripts in MyApp.jsp

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="myapp/myapp.nocache.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="myapp/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="myapp/js/slimbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="myapp/js/slider.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then I have MainPage.java, which creation is handled by History

```
public MainPage() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    RootLayoutPanel.get().clear();
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(this);
    onLoadSlider();
}

public static native void onLoadSlider() /*-{
    $("#slider").easySlider({
    auto: true,
    continuous: true,
    controlsShow: false,
});
}-*/;
```

calling the onLoadSlider function results to exception: `onLoadSlider()([]): $ is not defined`

then I tried to use `window.top.document.getElementById("slider")` instead of `$("#slider")` and exception is now `onLoadSlider()([]): undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read up in the [official dev guide for JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#writing), you have to prepend `$wnd` here:

```
$wnd.$("#slider").easySlider({
    auto: true,
    continuous: true,
    controlsShow: false,
});
```

> When accessing the browser's window and document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as **$wnd** and $doc, respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host page's window and document.

Comment: Other way around @apanizo - GWT apps run in a different 'window' (really an iframe), so the 'real' window is referenced as $wnd. This means that two obfuscated GWT apps can't accidentally reference each other, or a JS app can't be confused by GWT compiled functions. Same is true for $doc instead of document. The `window.alert` still works in some browsers because those browsers don't care which window the alert function gets called on.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$wnd.parent.document.getElementById("slider")
```

instead of

```
window.top.document.getElementById("slider")
```